# Visual C++ doesn't see my class

Tags: visual-c++

I was trying to make a basic class program to practice making classes, however even though I followed a tutorial visual ++ says `Person() expression must have a class type.`

I don't really understand what it's saying and didn't find anything after looking it up. here is my code:

```
//My main program

// ConsoleApplication1.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Person.h"

using namespace std;
int main(){
    Person person();
    cout << person.getName() << "Age = " << person.getAge() << endl;
    return 0;
}

//My person.cpp file

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "person.h"
Person::Person() {
    name = "unknown";
    age = 0;
}

string Person::getName() {
    return "person's name is " + name;
}

int Person::getAge() {
    return age;
}

//My person.h file

#pragma once
#include "Person.cpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
class Person {
private:
    string name;
    int age;

public:
    Person(); 
    string getName();
    int getAge();

};
```

Comment: `Person person();` is a declaration of a function taking no parameters and returning a `Person` (compare with, say, `int main()`) - not a declaration of a variable. Make it `Person person;` or, if you want the default initialization to be explicit, `Person person{};`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand on what @Igor Tandetnik is saying when you are creating the instance of `Person` you are actually declaring a function which is called `person` and returns a data type of `Person`. This function takes no parameters, hence: `()`. What you want to do is

```
int main(){
     Person person;
     //...

     //...
}
```

doing it this way creates an instance of a `Person` called `person`, or in easier terms creating a `Person` called `bob` would be `Person bob;` and not `Person bob();`